# How to convert parquet schema to avro in Java/Scala

Tags: hadoop, avro, parquet, parquet-mr

Let say I have parquet file on the file system. How can I get parquet schema and convert it to Avro Schema?

Comment: Even though your answer uses scala, your question is not about either [tag:java] nor [tag:scala], and thus those tags are not appropriate for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [hadoop ParquetFileReader](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-hadoop/src/main/java/org/apache/parquet/hadoop/ParquetFileReader.java) to get Parquet schema and pass it to [AvroSchemaConverter](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-avro/src/main/java/org/apache/parquet/avro/AvroSchemaConverter.java) to convert it to Avro schema.
Scala code example:

```
import org.apache.avro.Schema

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path

import org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroSchemaConverter
import org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader
import org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopInputFile

object ParquetToAvroSchemaConverter {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val path = new Path("###PATH_TO_PARQUET_FILE###")
    val avroSchema = convert(path)
  }

  def convert(parquetPath: Path): Schema = {
    val cfg = new Configuration
    // Create parquet reader
    val rdr = ParquetFileReader.open(HadoopInputFile.fromPath(parquetPath, cfg))
    try {
      // Get parquet schema
      val schema = rdr.getFooter.getFileMetaData.getSchema
      println("Parquet schema: ")
      println("#############################################################")
      print(schema.toString)
      println("#############################################################")
      println

      // Convert to Avro
      val avroSchema = new AvroSchemaConverter(cfg).convert(schema)
      println("Avro schema: ")
      println("#############################################################")
      println(avroSchema.toString(true))
      println("#############################################################")

      avroSchema
    }
    finally {
      rdr.close()
    }
  }
}
```

You have to have next dependencies in your `SBT` project:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.parquet" % "parquet-avro" % "1.10.0",
  "org.apache.parquet" % "parquet-hadoop" % "1.10.0",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.7.3",
)
```